# SQL SELECT items With Different Categories

Tags: sql, mariadb

Here is the table:

- itemcode
- batch
- subbatch
- desc

| itemcode | batch | subbatch | desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | red |
| B | 1 | 1 | red |
| C | 9 | 1 | red |
| C | 9 | 2 | blue |
| D | 8 | 1 | red |
| D | 8 | 2 | blue |
| E | 2 | 1 | red |
| F | 3 | 1 | red |
| G | 4 | 1 | red |
| H | 1 | 1 | red |
| I | 9 | 1 | red |
| I | 9 | 2 | blue |
| J | 8 | 1 | red |
| J | 8 | 2 | blue |

There are two kinds of items, one item with just 1 batch and 1 subbatch, the other item has 1 batch and multiple subbatch.

I want to select all items with the 1 batch / 1 subbatch including the other items with 1 batch and a specific subbatch.  In this case, items with batch 8 or 9 has multiple subbatch.  I wanted to select all items that is not in batch 8 or 9 plus items with batch 8 or 9 with subbatch 2.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: All items from 1-7 and all items from 8-9 but only a specified sub-batch.

Comment: It seems that is what Gordon's answer produces?

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe you can use `not exists` with boolean logic:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.itemcode = t.itemcode and
                        t2.subbatch <> t.subbatch
                 ) or
      subbatch = 2;
```